# Count the number of lists using recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

This is what I've tried:

```
def recursive_list_counter(l):
    sum = 0
    for e in l:
        if type(e) == type([]):
            #print e
            sum += 1
            recursive_list_counter(e)
    return sum 

# should be 6 if I count the first also
recursive_list_counter([[[13, 7], 90], 2, [1, 100, [5, [2]]], 8, 6])
```

I want to use recursion to retrieve the number of lists within a list, counting the original list also.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your recursive call *ignores* what is returned. Add the return value:

```
def recursive_list_counter(l):
    sum = 0
    for e in l:
        if isinstance(e, list):
            sum += 1
            sum += recursive_list_counter(e)
    return sum
```

Note that the *outer list* is ignored in the count, so the call returns 5, not 6.

Furthermore, you should use `isinstance()` to test if an object is of a given type.

If you want to see `6`, count the *current* list in the function, and leave counting nested lists to the recursive call:

```
def recursive_list_counter(l):
    sum = 1
    for e in l:
        if isinstance(e, list):
            sum += recursive_list_counter(e)
    return sum
```

Comment: I would change `type(e) == type([])` this part

Comment: To count the outer list, just start with `sum = 1` and lose `sum += 1`.

Answer (score 9):

For your given example, if all you have are numbers within lists, you can try converting to string and counting the number of `[`

```
>>> li = [[[13, 7], 90], 2, [1, 100, [5, [2]]], 8, 6]
>>> str(li).count('[') 
6
```

Comment: But of course your solution fails miserably as soon as there is s string inside the list containing an opening bracket.  And it is way to costly because generating the string representation is not necessary for this task.

Comment: @Alfe I know, but still, its awesome!

Comment: @Alfe Agree with the part this fails if there are strings with the bracket in one of the lists. My answer begins with the assumption that is not the case. Disagree with converting to string being costly, recursion implies call stack, and I won't be too sure on which is faster, without proper tests.

Comment: This is a nice trick and all, but the OP was asking about recursion. :-)

Comment: Nice trick, agreed, but has drawbacks which I wouldn't want to support, hence my critique.  Consider an element whose `str` function takes lots of time.

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do the trick.
But I guess I was too slow, I already see 3 other answers. :P

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def lcount(l):
    count = 0 
    if isinstance(l, list):
        count+=1
        count+=sum([lcount(x) for x in l]) 

    return count


list_ = [ [ [1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 5], [7, 8, 9]], [ 1, 2, 7], 1, 3, ]
print lcount(list_)
```

Comment: @user2144553 I'm not sure how you're running this or what input you're using but, runs for me, see http://ideone.com/2InIOy for live example

Answer (score 3):

A true functional solution would be this:

```
def recursive_list_counter(li):
  return 1 + sum(map(recursive_list_counter, li)) if isinstance(li, list) else 0
```

To count all elements in the list use this slightly altered version:

```
def recursive_element_counter(li):
  return sum(map(recursive_element_counter, li)) if isinstance(li, list) else 1
```

Comment: Maybe you are trying an outdated version of my answer?

Comment: Actually I copied element counter by mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Three important points:

- use `isinstance` to check the type
- don't use `sum` as a variable since it's already a built-in function
- recursive fonctions should start with the stopping condition (here: `not isinstance(l, list)`)

Here is your function :

```
def recursive_list_counter(l):
    if not isinstance(l, list):
        return 0
    return 1 + sum(recursive_list_counter(e) for e in l)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the problem is very simple. Everytime you called `recursive_list_counter`, you create a new local variable `sum`, instead of incrementing the global one.

```
sum = 0
def recursive_list_counter(l):
    global sum
    for e in l:
        if type(e) is list: #this is the same, but a better practice.
            #print e
            sum += 1
            recursive_list_counter(e)
    return sum 

recursive_list_counter([[[13, 7], 90], 2, [1, 100, [5, [2]]], 8, 6]) #returns 5
```

You can also increment sum recursively:

```
if type(e) is list:
    sum += 1
    sum += recursive_list_counter(e)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: **If** you are going to test for the specific type, use `is`: `type(e) is list`; but it is *much* better to use `isinstance()` because then you allow for subclasses of list as well.

Comment: Hi, your comment #returns 6 is a bit misleading! Your code actually returns 5, but that's normal since we start in a list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, i forgot that for a second.